# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I managed to install phpBB3 for the first time in my entire life with php5 and mysql. It was pretty interesting experience and the forum worked for few days. Then suddenly the server went down for several hours and I got email that it was because of the new kernel update.

Anyway, server is back up but I am getting this error:

```
  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) [2002]
```

I tried to read several topics about this on the internet, and it seems like I am missing the whole mysqld.sock file. As I am using this command:

```
find / -name '*.sock'
```

It returns nothing.

I also checked the status of mysql, it says:

```
mysql start/post-start, process 9905
    post-start process 9906
```

So I really can't tell what am I supposed to do. How do I solve this and get the forum back on?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please ask at [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Why are all similar problems leading to stackoverflow then?

Comment: maybe they have changed the mysql server version as well, and your configuration no longer matches the binary? Check mysql logs about what they say, there should be a mention of the socket file as well. Or raise a ticket to your hosting to check, since you might not have access yourself.